# SqlConnecton.OpenAsync hangs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, async-await

I am trying to do async programming involving SQL Server (there could be thousands of records so I want the UI freezing). This is my method:

```
Private Async Function ExecuteSqlTransaction(connectionString As String) As Task
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Await connection.OpenAsync()

    Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing

    'Dim lst As List(Of String) = ReadIntoList()

    Dim rowCount As Integer = Me._rows.Count()

    'Dim headers As String() = GetHeaders().ToArray()
    'Dim columns As String() = lst.ToArray()

    ' Start a local transaction.
    transaction = Await Task.Run(Of SqlTransaction)(Function() connection.BeginTransaction("AuditTransaction"))

    ' Must assign both transaction object and connection
    ' to Command object for a pending local transaction
    command.Connection = connection
    command.Transaction = transaction

    Try
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.CommandText = _procedure
        'Add the audut id
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Audit_ID", Me._auditId)
        For i As Integer = 0 To rowCount
            For j As Integer = 0 To Me._headers.Count() - 1
                If Me._headers(j).IndexOf(".") > 0 Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Me._headers(j).Substring(Me._headers(j).IndexOf(".")), Me._rows(i)(j))
                Else
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Me._headers(j), Me._rows(i)(j))
                End If
            Next

            Await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

            command.Parameters.Clear()
        Next

        ' Attempt to commit the transaction.
        Await Task.Run(Sub() transaction.Commit())
        Debug.Print("Audit items are written to database.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType())
        Debug.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message)

        ' Attempt to roll back the transaction.
        Try
            transaction.Rollback()
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            ' This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
            ' on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
            ' a closed connection.
            Debug.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType())
            Debug.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message)
        End Try
    End Try
    'End Using
End Function
```

And here is how I'm calling it:

```
Public Function ImportData() As Boolean
        Try
            ConvertExcelToCsv()

            Me._headers = GetHeaders()
            Me._rows = ReadIntoList()

            Dim task As Task = ExecuteSqlTransaction(Me._connString)
            task.Wait()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me._returnMessage = String.Format("ImportData Error: {0}", ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

It gets to the OpenAsync and just sits there spinning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a deadlock because you're calling `Task.Wait`, as I [explain in full on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The best solution is to use "async all the way"; that is, declare `ImportData` as returning a `Task (of Boolean)` and use `Await task` instead of `task.Wait()`.

Comment: thanks, that got rid of the deadlock but raises another question; When I was calling ImportData I was checking for true or false returned, returning a Task(Of Boolean) I cannot check he value that way, any ideas? (Sorry new to async programming)

Comment: You need to use `Await` to "unwrap" the `Boolean` from the `Task(Of Boolean)`. It is natural for async/await to "grow" up through the code like this.